# How to mock an instance attribute initilized by a function

Tags: python, mocking, patch

I'm writing some unit tests for a class that has instance attributes set in a function that is not the constructor. The class looks like this

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__A = False
        self.__B = False

    def set_C(self):
        self.__C = True

    def my_func(self):
        self.set_C()

        if self.__A:
            self.print_val(self.__A)
        if self.__B:
            self.print_val(self.__B)
        if self.__C:
            self.print_val(self.__C)

    def print_val(self, val):
        print(val)
```

I'm trying to write a test for `my_func()` to check that `print_val()` runs if the attribute evaluates to true.
The test that I have so far is this (ignoring imports)

```
class TestMyClass:

    @patch("MyClass.print_val")
    def test_my_func(self, mock_print_val):
        my_class = MyClass()
        # setattr(my_class, "C", False)
        with patch.object(my_class, "C", True) as mock_C:
            my_class.my_func()
            mock_print_val.assert_called()
```

I will be editing the assert call later to check that it was called with specific parameters but the basic idea is to check that *print_val()* runs.

I noticed that without `setattr(my_class, "C", False)` would give me the following error `AttributeError: <...> does not have attribute 'C'`.

With the `setattr()` when I debug I would be able to see "C" attribute under **Protected Attributes** in the variable window right before I print it but it still gives an error
(I'm actually not sure if `setattr()` is the correct way to go, just that I was trying stuff out since it said attribute does not exist)

I also know that if I change the code to the following to patch the attribute from `__init__` it works just fine

```
class TestMyClass:

    @patch("MyClass.print_val")
    def test_my_func(self, mock_print_val):
        my_class = MyClass()
        with patch.object(my_class, "A", True) as mock_C:
            my_class.my_func()
            mock_print_val.assert_called()
```

From the research I've done I've seen similar problems but they were for class attributes or were slightly different. I apologize if this question had been asked before and I missed it.

**Edit:**
While trying to figure out the solution I noticed that I could simply do

```
class TestMyClass:

    @patch("MyClass.print_val")
    def test_my_func(self, mock_print_val):
        my_class = MyClass()
        my_class.C = True
        my_class.my_func()
        mock_print_val.assert_called()
```

If the attribute `C` was public and printing it as `print_val(self.C)` would cause no problems. I edited the original question to clarify that the attribute is supposed to be protected and not public.

Answer (score 0):

While working on other tests I managed figure out a solution..

What I have is:

```
class TestMyClass:

    @patch("MyClass.print_val")
    def test_my_func(self, mock_print_val):
        my_class = MyClass()
        my_class._MyClass__C = True
        my_class.my_func()
        mock_print_val.assert_called()
```

This seemed to work. If the attribute in `MyClass` was prefixed with a single underscore or not prefixed at all `my_class._C` or `my_class._c` could be used but since it was prefixed with two underscores I had to do `my_class._MyClass__C`.

I do not know if this is a safe and recommended solution though..

Comment: For testing, I would say it's fine. The name-mangling applied to `__`-prefixed names is to make it harder to accidentally shadow a name in a child class. Given that you are using name-mangling, this is the way to access the attribute from outside a method.